# Azure Http Triggers function calls

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

I would like a Http Trigger function to call another Http Trigger function.
Basically, I am trying to access via the URL (HTTP request) the Trigger 1, which that Trigger 1 will call Trigger 2. 
What I am thinking is to put the fix URL for Trigger 2, so you just call Trigger 1.
Any ideas how to do that?

```
using System.Net;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    // parse query parameter
    string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
        .Value;

    // Get request body
    dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

    // Set name to query string or body data
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    return name == null
        ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
        : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: using webrequest it should work ? I tried but is not working

Comment: Don't put a standard example into your answer. Instead, show what you tried yourself to solve this problem.

Comment: I have tried     WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://testing.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerCSharp1?name=testing");
    WebResponse webResp = webRequest.GetResponse();

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `HttpClient` to do a normal HTTP request. Here is what the calling function could look like:

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req)
{
    var url = "https://<functionapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/Function2?code=<code>";
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Function 1 " + result);
}
```

Comment: error CS1061: 'HttpResponseMessage' does not contain a definition for 'content' and no extension method 'content' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpResponseMessage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

            static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage Request)
            {
                var url = "https://";
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Function 1 " + result);
        }

Comment: I tried the above in azure functions still an error. Can you please help on that?

Comment: Is your binding name `Request`? It's `req' by default. Otherwise code is correct. Which error you get?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-sequence) instead:

```
public static async Task<object> Run(DurableOrchestrationContext ctx)
{
    var x = await ctx.CallActivityAsync<object>("YourOtherFunctionName");
    // Rest of Function code
}
```

Comment: This is technically correct and probably the preferred way but only if your Function App is running on version 2.x

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
var url ="azure function URL with code and params";
using var client = new HttpClient();
client.GetAsync(url).Wait();
```